# M68k Big Endian to Little Endian

Tags: programming, m68k

I'm trying to write a binary file using vasm68k_mot (Motorola 68k) writing File-Size and File-Offset everything goes well, except that M68K is Big-Endian, there's a way I can change to Little-Endian in a simple way?

Let's say that the FileZ.bin has a size of 30Kb, this in hex should be 0x7530 in my binary file it writes in hex value "00 00 75 30", but I need to mirror that value to "30 75 00 00" The same applies for the file offset address.

I'm sorry if this is confusing, I'm not a programmer nor expert in ASM.

My code is like this:

```
dc.l    0,(FILEY_END-FILEY_START)               
dc.l    FILEZ_START,(FILEZ_END-FILEZ_START)
dc.l    FILEX_START,(FILEX_END-FILEX_START)  
cnop    0,2048



FILEZ_START
    incbin C:\FileZ.BIN
FILEZ_END
    cnop    0,2048

FILEX_START
FILEY_START
    incbin C:\FileY.BIN
FILEY_END
    cnop    0,2048
    incbin C:\FileX.bin
FILEX_END
```

EDIT: The documentation provided by @AlexHajnal is the same i'm using, thank you! I also will link it here: http://sun.hasenbraten.de/vasm/release/vasm.pdf

EDIT: All I need to is SWAP those "dc.l" values, they are 4 bytes long, I tried writing

```
ROL.W   #8,D0
SWAP    D0
ROL.W   #8,D0
```

but i got some random numbers, it may be related to vasmm68k_mot, but i really don't know....

Comment: Do you want to perform endian conversion while the program is running, or do you want it hardcoded in your file already endian-converted?

Comment: (By the way, this seems a pure programming question either way; regular Stack Overflow may be a better place for it.)

Comment: @AlexHajnal Good work, if it is the one. Looks promising to provide a macro. ;-)

Comment: @user3840170 I want to perform the BE to LE while the program is running, if possible, of course.

Comment: I'm not sure how this file is intended to be used but I think the first line should be `dc.l FILEY_START,(FILEY_END-FILEY_START)` rather than `dc.l 0,(FILEY_END-FILEY_START)`.  That's assuming that the first 2kB block contains pointers and lengths within the file.

Comment: I've corrected the code here aswell, now it's exactly what the code looks like. Yes, the file contains file lengths and pointers aligned to a 0x800 value, the first 4 bytes are null. In the next 4 bytes it cames the file length I mentioned, but in the opposite way that it should be.

Comment: The "random numbers" you're getting are the 68000 machine code values for the assembly language instructions you entered (you are using an assembler after all).  To do what you're trying to do you 1) can **not** use any assembly language instructions (e.g. `ROL.W` or `SWAP`) and 2) cannot use the assembler with a 68000 target (you **must** choose a little-endian target such as x86).

Comment: Do you have an executable named `vasmx86_std` or something similarly-named?

Comment: Yes, i have it. But everytime i run the code on this one i get lots and lots of errors and the final binary file isn't converted.

Comment: Yea, the syntax for the various target is a little different.  See my updated answer for details.

Comment: _"All I need to is SWAP those "dc.l" values, they are 4 bytes long"_ - Why do you want to do this? What is the purpose of the 'dc.l' values?

Comment: @BruceAbbott The OP is creating a file with embedded records padded to 2kB boundaries.  The first 2kB block contains up to 256 entries giving the offset in the file of each record along with the record's length, both in bytes.  The OP's application apparently requires that the offsets and lengths be in 32-bit little-endian format.  Each record is loaded from an external file (e.g. `FileX.BIN`).  I'm not sure why they have the index block's offset (`0`) as the first entry's offset (I would think it should be `FILEY_START`).  I'm also not sure why there are overlapping records (X and Y).

Comment: @Chenmunka This question has three answers, each of which interprets the question in a different way, and it’s not even clear that the accepted one is what the asker meant. How is it not worthy of closure as unclear?

Comment: @user3840170 All I was in need was a way to assemble a certain binary file structured in Little-Endian format, but the program that I was using (vasmm68k_mot) couldn't do that. So, Alex pointed another tool (vasmx86_std) that could be used to do what for what I need, as you can see I'm not a ASM pro, far-less a programmer. That's all basically. Alex not only gave me a solution to my problem, but pointed out my mistake for using a program that will always compile in Big-Endian, he also showed how to use this new tool that he mentioned. I haven't yet tested thebusybee solution.

Comment: @Raoni I'm curious, what led you to choose vasm for the task?

Comment: @AlexHajnal It was the first assembler I saw that I could use it, it was "simple". It become more easy to do something using the manual and some .asm files as example. Before that, I always used some Hex edit to edit some files for personal use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My original take on the question:

For longs (32-bit), this is [answered here](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15365/7347).  For shorts (16-bit) just use `ROL.W #8, D0`.

---

If @thebusybee's interpretation of the question is correct (which appears to be the case) then the answer would appear to be "No" (when targeting MC68000).  From page 6 of [the vasm manual](http://sun.hasenbraten.de/vasm/release/vasm.pdf):

```
... a constant is built according to the endianess of the target.
```

However, if you change the target to something little-endian (e.g. x86 instead of 68000) then computed values will be stored as little-endian.

To use a different target you'll need to change the syntax of your assembler source file.  For example, the x86 equivalent of the source you posted (as of 2021-05-19 21:45Z) is:

```
.long 0,FILEY_END-FILEY_START
.long FILEZ_START,FILEZ_END-FILEZ_START
.long FILEX_START,FILEX_END-FILEX_START  
.balign    2048



FILEZ_START:
    .incbin C:\FileZ.BIN
FILEZ_END:
    .balign    2048

FILEX_START:
FILEY_START:
    .incbin C:\FileY.BIN
FILEY_END:
    .balign    2048
    .incbin C:\FileX.BIN
FILEX_END:
```

The above should be placed in a file named `file.s`

To create your output file (to be named `file.bin`) run:

```
vasmx86_std -Fbin -o file.bin file.s
```

You may need to tweak the file names/paths above (I tested on Linux then added the `C:\` prefixes to what I posted above).

Comment: I understand the question this way: The bytes should be stored in LE directly. The OP did not ask for some code to swap. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @AlexHajnal, i'm using both dc.w and dc.l, Where can I add the ROL and SWAP into my code?

Comment: @thebusybee I won't mind a code to swap, if this mirrors the value :-), But I don't know how can I use the ROL and SWAP functions into the .asm file...

Comment: @Raoni Code swaps during runtime by execution of the processor. And if you don't know how to apply the suggestions, you have a bigger problem. You need to learn, honestly. BTW, `ROL` and `SWAP` are not functions, they are instructions to the target processor.

Comment: On the original 68000, the rotate-left instruction is sufficiently slow that loading two bytes separately and then storing two bytes separately will sometimes be faster than loading a 16-bit word, performing a rotate left, and then storing the result.

Comment: @AlexHajnal: A shift count can only be specified for in-register form of the instruction; the form that accepts an "effective address" always shifts by one bit.

Comment: @supercat And that's what I get for posting while exhausted.

Comment: @AlexHajnal I don't even know what to say.... It's working like a charm! Thank you a lot for your time and effort for this!

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

This is just an alternative for the poor lost souls coming here for help. ;-)

Instead of code to be run by the processor, this solution generates a 32-bit value in little endian right in place.

The assembler has macro capabilities, and a macro can be used:

- `dc_l_le` is the name of the macro. Look at it as a new pseudo instruction. It means "define constant, long, little endian".
- The macro handles different number of expressions, tested with 2, but I'm sure there is a limit.
- The number of expressions is obtained by `\#` and used for a repetition loop.
- The n-th expression can be obtained by `\+`. This special value inserts one expression after the other. On each repetition the local symbol `.value` is set to the expression.
- Shifting and masking separates the bytes.

```
dc_l_le macro
        rept    \#
.value  set     \+
        dc.b    (.value>>0)&$FF
        dc.b    (.value>>8)&$FF
        dc.b    (.value>>16)&$FF
        dc.b    (.value>>24)&$FF
        endr
        endm

    org $12345678

    dc_l_le 0,(FILEY_END-FILEY_START)               
    dc_l_le FILEZ_START,(FILEZ_END-FILEZ_START)
    dc_l_le FILEX_START,(FILEX_END-FILEX_START)  
    cnop    0,2048



FILEZ_START
    incbin FileZ.BIN
FILEZ_END
    cnop    0,2048

FILEX_START
FILEY_START
    incbin FileY.BIN
FILEY_END
    cnop    0,2048
    incbin FileX.bin
FILEX_END
```

*Note: This otherwise good looking assembler cannot handle whitespace in expressions. I'd love to write `(.value >> 24) & $FF` but this led to irritating error messages. It took some time to find the reason.*

**EDIT:**

The command line for this suggestion is:

`vasmm68k_mot.exe -Fbin -o test.bin -L test.lst test.S`

The specific output format is not important, I think, and the listing is generated just to see that the solution works. The "`S`" source extension is deliberately chosen out of habbits.

The assembler shows these versions, I used the provided binary on Win10:

```
vasm 1.8k (c) in 2002-2021 Volker Barthelmann
vasm M68k/CPU32/ColdFire cpu backend 2.4 (c) 2002-2021 Frank Wille
vasm motorola syntax module 3.15a (c) 2002-2021 Frank Wille
vasm binary output module 2.1 (c) 2002-2021 Volker Barthelmann and Frank Wille
```

To avoid relocation errors, an `org` pseudo instruction is added just for demonstration, but the real thing is most probably allocated in other ways.

Comment: I tried assembling this using `vasm68k_mot` but got `illegal relocation` errors for the `dc.b` lines.  What command line did you use?  (also, adding `-cnop=0x0000` to the command line might be desirable)

Comment: Well, what is your command line? (Optimally you add it to your question.)

Comment: I used `./vasmm68k_mot -Fbin -o test2.bin test2.s` but got the same result with `./vasmm68k_mot -Fbin -o test2.bin -L test2.lst test2.s`  The errors are: `error 39 in line 2 of "REPEAT:dc_l_le:line 7": illegal relocation` `called from line 7 of "dc_l_le"` `called from line 12 of "test2.s"` `>        dc.b    (.value>>0)&$FF` ...   The assembler was compiled on Linux from the [latest source release](http://sun.hasenbraten.de/vasm/index.php?view=relsrc) (source release 1.8k: vasm 1.8k, vasm M68k/CPU32/ColdFire cpu backend 2.4, vasm motorola syntax module 3.15a, vasm binary output module 2.1).

Comment: Since I presumed that you showed us just a cut-out, there is no `ORG` in my source. I'll add it.

Comment: Adding `org $0` after the macro definition makes it work fine.

Comment: @AlexHajnal Oh, sorry, I mixed you up with the OP.

Comment: That's OK.  It does need to be `org $0` though since the OP's is using the assembler to create a raw binary file (not a machine code program).  Also, the `-cnop=0x000` option can be used to get NULLs for padding (default 68k padding is 0x4E71 BE).

Comment: In this case it does not matter, apparently. The generated binary file does not contain the first zillions bytes. I chose that value to get different bytes in the addresses.

Comment: Using different (non-zero) `org` values does change the computed values though as well as the alignment of the records within the file.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Since there is no explicit requirement, I can use any number. ;-) This is also true for the filling pattern. However, the solution is not about a specific case, it is a guide **_how_** to use a macro to generate little endians. Using it without thinking and understanding would be an error. That's the purpose of this site.

Comment: Yea, I think your answer is good.  Just mentioning what I noticed when trying it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know something about the file data, I think the simple answer is 'no'. If the data was bytes, they would be in the same order. If it was 16-bit words, they would be swapped in pairs. If it was 32-bit words, then 4 bytes would be reversed.

I would imagine you could look at a dump of the data and make a reasonable guess most of the time. But there is no simple swapEndian.exe tool that can do it for you.

[Off-topic, but I am now intrigued: I wonder how good a neural net might be at guessing and swapping?]

Comment: From the OP's later comments it sounds like they want to force the endian-ness of the values computed by vasm, not the values read from external files (i.e. from `C:\FileZ.BIN` *et al.*).  With vasm, the endian-ness used for computed values is determined by the chosen target (MC68000 in this case, which is big-endian) and vasm provides no option to change this behaviour.  To get the computed values in little-endian they need to switch to a little-endian target (such as x86).